# Javascript math.random gives too many duplicate values

Tags: javascript, node.js, random

Using NodeJS 14. I have a script that needs to generate 10,000 unique numbers between 1 and 10000.  i have a function that takes 1 as min and 10000 as max. When I run it, only ~7000 are unique the rest are duplicates. I understand that not all 10k would be unique, but 30%?  What can I do to get more of then unique?

function is:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

sorted sample
1856
1871
1873
1879
1879
1885
1895
1903
1911
1911

Comment: The number of non-unique numbers should statistically be way higher than 30% i think. Regardless, this if you ask for a random number over and over again the chance of getting duplicates will go up dramatically.

Comment: Just tested but 30ish percent is right and makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

To obtain exactly 10000 unique random numbers, you can just shuffle all the integers from 1 to 10000.

```js
let nums = Array.from({length:10000}, (_, i) => i + 1);
for (let i = nums.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  const j = Math.random() * (i + 1) | 0;
  [nums[i], nums[j]] = [nums[j], nums[i]];
}
console.log(nums);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the size of the set an keep pushing into it until the size if your desired size. Set guarantees uniquness.

```
const uniqueNumbers = new Set(); 

while (uniqueNumbers.size < 10000) { 
  let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1; 
  uniqueNumbers.add(randomNum); 
}

//set to array
console.log([...uniqueNumbers]);
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to take into account that the  objective is to create a random permutation of numbers in  the range `[1, 1000]`, not a set of random numbers.

Comment: @jayant this code is still not good for the given purpose, the further it progresses, the more iterations it takes to find another number. your code takes around 110000 iterations in my browser. That's an average of 11 iterations per number.

Comment: @Thomas - a random integer in range 1-1000.  My observation is that this is a brute force method to arrange the set of numbers between 1 and 1000  into random order.

Comment: @traktor OK, I read your initial comment as *doesn't produce the correct result*.